# What could be causing 'connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9090' error in Postman while testing a Java project?

Tags: java

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aB16B.png)

I'm trying to running my project and am using a postman for testing purpose but am trying to send a request it's give me an error Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9090. I'm tried to solve this error

Comment: There's no server running at 127.0.0.1:9090?

Answer (score -2):

Check the service port of your service, maybe you are trying to connect through the wrong port. The most common port for Spring applications is 8080

Comment: FileZilla? Not sure how that's related.

Comment: `ECONNREFUSED` is an error thrown by the node.js `http` module when the server you're sending a request to refuses the connection. Postman is made with node.js. If you look at the screenshot the OP provided (or the tags, or actually read the question), you can see that Postman is the one producing this error. This has nothing to do with FileZilla.